# Fit any number into 12 digits

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm using .eval() to get a number, but I need to fit the number into a a space where only twelve digits will fit, I'd like to be able to round where there will always be twelve digits shown. I thought .toExponential() would solve this but often the values from that are longer than 12 digits also. My current code looks like this -

```
function enter() {
  string = eval(string);
  console.log(string.toExponential());
  if (string.toString().length > 12) {
    string = string.toExponential();
    updateDisplay();
  } else {
    updateDisplay();
  }
}
```

Any way to handle this?

Comment: Why are you using eval to get number at all... string is defined elsewhere, and evaling arbitrary input allows code injection.

Comment: whatever you want to achieve you won't be able to put 13 digits into 12 without any loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be some good answer of this question but this is what comes in my mind after reading your question

firstly convert no to sting.

```
function enter(no)
{
var x=no.toString();
var newnum=x.substring(0,11);
//check for roundoff 
if (Number(x.substring(12))>5)
newnum=Number(newnum)+1;
else 
newnum=Number(newnum);
return newnum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to compress the number to another `radix`.

This will require a `decompress` call when evaluation the string, but it will allow you to fit bigger numbers in tinier spots.

```js
function compressNumber(number) {
  return number.toString(36);
}

function decompressNumber(number) {
  return parseInt(number, 36);
}
//Test
console.log("Basic number", 5, compressNumber(5));
console.log('Base 16 example', 15, compressNumber(15));
console.log('A "1" followed by 11 zeroes', Math.pow(10, 11), compressNumber(Math.pow(10, 11)));
console.log('A "1" followed by 11 zeroes, negative', -Math.pow(10, 11), compressNumber(-Math.pow(10, 11)));
console.log('A "1" followed by 11 zeroes, decompressing', Math.pow(10, 11), decompressNumber(compressNumber(Math.pow(10, 11))));
console.log('Biggest 12 digit compressed number', Math.pow(10, 11).toString().replace(/\d/ig, 'z'));
console.log('Biggest 12 digit compressed number decompressed', decompressNumber(Math.pow(10, 11).toString().replace(/\d/ig, 'z')));
```